# C# WPF - DataGrid Binding Troubles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a custom DataGrid in which one of the columns contains a TextBox that is bound to a Table column. I have one DataTable to populate the Grid that does not actually exist in the actual Database (just the Dataset) that is used to populate and update a DataTable that is linked ot the actual Database. Everything else inserts just fine, but not the Comments field. Instead it always ends up as what I initialized it as ("") - the user's input is not saved. I thought the Binding would automatically update the DataTable, but this does not appear to be the case. What might be a good solution?

The XAML for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" x:Name="itemGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  MinHeight="400" Height="400" Width="800"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" CanUserResize="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Points Possible" Binding="{Binding Points}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Deductions" Width="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox   Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Score}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="updateScore" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Score}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="updateScore" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"   Width="50" Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Current}"  />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comments" MinWidth="100" Width="300">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Comments}" Margin="10" Width="Auto" Height="100"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Comments, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10" Width="Auto" Height="100"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and some snippets from my C# code

```
try { con.Open(); }
        catch (SqlException er) { Console.Write(er); }

        String query = "SELECT * from dbo.locations";
       locAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        locAdapter.Fill(ds, "Locations");



        query = "SELECT * from dbo.report_summary";
        reportAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        reportAdapter.Fill(ds, "Reports");
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT into dbo.report_summary ( report_id, inspector, employee, room, date, score, locationID) " + " VALUES ( @report_id, @inspector, @employee, @room, @date, @score, @locationID)", con);
        insert.Parameters.Add("@report_id", SqlDbType.Char, 5, "report_id");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@room", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "room");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@inspector", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "inspector");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@employee", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "employee");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "date");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@score", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "score");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@locationID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "locationID");
        reportAdapter.InsertCommand = insert;


        query = "SELECT * from dbo.report_details";
       detailsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        detailsAdapter.Fill(ds, "Details");

     insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT into dbo.report_details (reportID, itemID, points, comments) " + " VALUES (@reportID, @itemID, @points, @comments)", con);
        insert.Parameters.Add("@reportID", SqlDbType.Char, 5, "reportID");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@itemID", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "itemID");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@points", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "points");
        insert.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.Text, 150, "comments");

        detailsAdapter.InsertCommand = insert;


        locationComboBox.DataContext = ds.Tables["Locations"];
        locationComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "locName";



        DataTable grid = new DataTable("Grid");
        grid.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        grid.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        grid.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(String));
        grid.Columns.Add("Points", typeof(int));
        grid.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(List<int>));
        grid.Columns.Add("Current", typeof(int));
        grid.Columns.Add("Comments", typeof(String));     



        query = "SELECT itemID, name, description, points, category FROM dbo.items";

        SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DataRow row = grid.NewRow();

            row["ID"] = reader["itemID"];
            row["Name"] = reader["name"];
            row["Description"] = reader["description"];
            row["Points"] = reader["points"];
            totalPoints += (int)reader["points"];
            row["Current"] = reader["points"];
            row["Comments"] = "";
            int pointsPossible = (int)reader["points"];
            List<int> rowList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = pointsPossible; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                rowList.Add(i);
            }
            rowList.Sort();
            row["Score"] = rowList;


            grid.Rows.Add(row);



        }
        ds.Tables.Add(grid);

        itemGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Grid"].DefaultView;






 private void updateDatabase()
        {
            SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();

            reportAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = tran;

            detailsAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = tran;

            DataRow reportRow = ds.Tables["Reports"].NewRow();

            reportRow["report_id"] = reportID;
            DataRowView inspectorSelection = (DataRowView)inspectorBox.SelectedItem;
            reportRow["inspector"] = Int16.Parse(inspectorSelection["empID"].ToString());

            DataRowView empSelection = (DataRowView)employeeBox.SelectedItem;
            reportRow["employee"] = Int16.Parse(inspectorSelection["empID"].ToString());

            DataRowView locationSelection = (DataRowView)locationComboBox.SelectedItem;
            reportRow["locationID"] = Int16.Parse(locationSelection["locID"].ToString());


            reportRow["room"] = Int16.Parse(roomTextBox.Text);

            reportRow["date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");



            reportRow["score"] = currentPoints;

            ds.Tables["Reports"].Rows.Add(reportRow);

            // update report_details dataset

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Grid"].Rows)
            {

                DataRow reportDetailsRow = ds.Tables["Details"].NewRow();

                reportDetailsRow["reportID"] = reportID;
                reportDetailsRow["itemID"] = row["ID"];
                reportDetailsRow["points"] = row["Current"];
             // figure out why comments are not being inserted 
                reportDetailsRow["comments"] = row["Comments"];

                ds.Tables["Details"].Rows.Add(reportDetailsRow);

            }

            // update tables as single transaction
            try
            {

                reportAdapter.Update(ds, "Reports");

                detailsAdapter.Update(ds, "Details");
                tran.Commit();


            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sqlEr.Message);
                tran.Rollback();
            }

        }
```

Thank you so so much for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but DataTable has an [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) function that perhaps you have to call before the changes are actually reflected.